# Pass Variable from UserForm to Module

Tags: excel, vba

I made a Login UserForm [UserForm here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsCiQ.png) and, I need the User & Pass variable in Module1 to be the same as written in UserForm UserBox.Text & PassBox.Text.

UserForm1

```
Public tempUser As String
Public tempPass As String

Private Sub Submit_Click()
    tempUser = UserBox.Text
    tempPass = PassBox.Text
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Back_Click()
    tempLogin = ""
    tempSenha = ""
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserBox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    HideTitleBarAndBordar Me
    MakeUserformTransparent Me
End Sub
```

Module1

```
Sub LogModule()

    UserForm1.Show

    User = UserForm1.tempUser
    Pass = UserForm1.tempPass

End Sub
```

Comment: Two issues i) you unload  the userform which means you lose `tempUser`and `tempPass` ii) you use the deafult instance which means the line `User = Userform1.tempuser` will initalize the userform and reset `tempUser`and `tempPass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note:***
Here is an option to make your code work, but it may not be the most optimal approach.

- Public variables should be declared in a standard module

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Declaring variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

**UserForm1**

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    tempUser = UserBox.Text
    tempPass = PassBox.Text
    Unload Me
End Sub

' Your code ...
```

**Module1**

```
Public tempUser As String
Public tempPass As String
Sub LogModule()
    UserForm1.Show
    User = tempUser
    Pass = tempPass
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer this approach:

LoginForm:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private m_cancelled As Boolean

Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Me.Hide '# not unload
End Sub

Private Sub Back_Click()
    m_cancelled = True
    Me.Hide '# not unload
End Sub

'handle manual close via "X"
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Back_Click
    Cancel = True
End Sub

'userform properties....
Property Get UserName() As String
    UserName = Me.txtUser.Value
End Property

Property Get Password() As String
    Password = Me.txtPass.Value
End Property

Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = m_cancelled
End Property
'/userform properties
```

Calling code:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim login As New LoginForm
    
    login.Show
    
    If login.Cancelled Then
        Debug.Print "cancelled"
    Else
        Debug.Print login.UserName, login.Password
    End If
    
    Unload login

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As *UserBox* and *PassBox* are exposed anyway you could shorten the approach a bit

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Cancelled As Boolean
Public Property Get Cancelled() As Variant
    Cancelled = m_Cancelled
End Property
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Hide
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
    , CloseMode As Integer)
    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
End Sub
Private Sub Back_Click()
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
End Sub
```

Testing

```
Sub getPass()
    Dim inpFrm As New UserForm1
    With inpFrm
        .Show
        If .Cancelled Then
            Debug.Print "Cancelled"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Submitted: ", .UserBox.Value, .PassBox.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You could even leave out `.value` as that is AFAIK the default property of the textbox control.

Further *reading*

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/
https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/